# What is the continuous version of "diagonal matrix"?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, linear-transformations, operator-theory

A diagonal matrix has the nice property that its eigenvectors span the space it acts on.

What if the space is infinite-dimensional? What would you call a diagonal operator?

Does the space have to be a Hilbert space? Banach space? How can we think about a diagonal operator on, say, $L^2[0,1]$?

Comment: What about $a_{i,k}=f_i \delta_{i,k} \to a(x,y)=f(x) \delta(x-y)$ ?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze This gives a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is only nonzero on the line $x=y$.. how is that related to the multiplication operator?

Comment: $T_f \phi(x) := \int f(y) \phi(y) \delta(x-y)\; dy = f(x) \phi(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generalization you are looking for is the [multiplication operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_operator) (examples in link).

The spectral theorem takes the following form in this case: [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Multiplication_operator_version).